# Is it possible to change the location of sorted video of image_picker plugin?

Tags: flutter

I am picking video from camera in this way. and using image_picker: ^0.6.7+22 plugin.

```
 final _picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<String> recordAndGetVideo()async{
    PickedFile file = await _picker.getVideo(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if(file != null){
      return file.path;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

After record ad video it stored the video and final path is this path. `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files/Pictures/a190e227-a42c-4b09-bad8-4a9591454ff64584234230431626592.mp4`

Now is it possible to store that video is different dir ?  like `/storage/emulated/0/Example App/a190e227-a42c-4b09-bad8-4a9591454ff64584234230431626592.mp4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, But you have to **re-write the file from one location to another**.

This is the only way.

Comment: Yes, that's thing i doing right now ! but its look like android is deprecating String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path !

Comment: You can manually set path if you dont want to use getExtStorageDir() like String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Example App/"